# Rendering PartialView via AJAX takes too long time in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

There is a Layout page in my MVC app and with the help of a menü link on this Layout page, I render a PartialView having only 5-6 input with no css or js import. As it can bee seen on the image below, it takes approximately 4 second just loading this PartialView and I think there is a big mistake regarding to this logic. Could you please have a look at the page and clarify me about where I did mistake?

**Note:** As far as I see the time consuming part of the AJAx method is in the success part (until $("#div-page-content").html(''); line). Is it needed or how can I change that part with a faster code block?

**LayoutPage:**

```
<a href="#" id="register" class="nav-link" onclick="renderPartial(event, 'Account', 'Create')">


<div id="div-page-content" class="page-content">
        @RenderBody()
</div>


<script>

    function renderPartial(e, controller, action) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var controllerName = controller;
        var actionName = action;

        if (String(actionName).trim() == '') {
            return false;
        }
        if (typeof (controllerName) == "undefined") {
            return false;
        }

        var url = "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { /* additional parameters */ },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",

            success: function (data) {
                var requestedUrl = String(this.url).replace(/[&?]X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest/i, "");
                if (typeof (requestedUrl) == "undefined" || requestedUrl == 'undefined') {
                    requestedUrl = window.location.href;
                }

                // if the url is the same, replace the state
                if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
                    if (window.location.href == requestedUrl) {
                        history.replaceState({ html: '' }, document.title, requestedUrl);
                    }
                    else {
                        history.pushState({ html: '' }, document.title, requestedUrl);
                    }
                }

                $("#div-page-content").html('');
                $("#div-page-content").append(data);
            },
            error: function (data) { onError(data); }
        });
    };

</script>
```

**_PartialView:**

```
<div>
   //... code omitted fr borevity (there is no js or css import in this view
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return PartialView("_Register");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Has anybody no idea?

Comment: It's not the AJAX that's the problem. The server is taking 3 seconds to respond to the request. It'll be the code running in either the action (in the controller) or the partial view that's taking the time to run.

Comment: @BenG I added the Action method to the end of the question. I realized that it takes too long fron returning Action method. But I could not understand why? May it be related to the return type (ActionResult instead of PartialViewResult)?

Comment: @JasonElkin Yes, you are right. The problem seems to be related to Action method, because the time is consumed in the Action method because the code hits to the success method of the Ajax method after several seconds. But I have no idea about what is the origin of the problem. Because the Action method seems to be so standard. Any idea? Thanks a lot...

Comment: For the last tests I see that the problem seems to be caused from the waiting the Action method. But how and why? Because the Action method is a standard method as it is used many project and it is really unbelievable. Any idea?

Comment: I also tr,ed to apply the method on http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/ by making an ampty partialview but it did not make any sense and still takes 5 seconds to render partialview :(

Comment: Silly question, but does this happen for _every_ request, or just the first one after running? Razor views go through a just-in-time compilation the first time they are rendered which will add a few seconds to the first request.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I realized that a little bit late. The first try takes 5 seconds while the latter ones get miliseconds and as far as I see it is normal for MVC applications. However, I am not sure if it is acceptable for a user to wait 5 second for every first requests after clearing his/her browser history. Any idea?

Comment: @binary this only happens after the site has been restarted and it only happens for the very first request made. All subsequent requests will be lightning fast until the site is rebooted again.

Comment: Many thanks Jason. If I did not misunderstood, clearing the web browser's cache does not affect the speed of the page load too much. Is that true?